# Binding issue in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-controlleras

I am trying to bind from a http get request.  The http get is returning true or false.  I have tested the get and it is returning properly.  When I run the code below, it shows the alert(1111) properly also.  However, when I'm trying to change the button text, nothing appears!   I have tried everything that I know to do.  Any advice would be helpful.

Post.js

```
myApp.controller('FollowController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    var status = "";

        $http.get('/Home/CheckFollower?idToFollow=' + profileId + '&followerId=' + currentUserId).
            success(function(data) {
                //check if it is a follower

                if (data) {
                    // Not following - Show unfollow
                    alert("1111");
                    $scope.statusMessage = data;


                } else {
                    //Following - show Follow

                    $scope.statusMessage = data;
                }

            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });

}]);
```

Html

```
   <span style="float: right" ng-controller="FollowController as follow">
                        <button type=" button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Follow", "Home", new { idToFollow = ViewBag.ProfileId, followerId = User.Identity.GetUserId() })'">
                            {{ follow.statusMessage }}</button>

                        </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the variables to `this` instead of `$scope` as you are using [**controllerAs approach**](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller('FollowController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        var status = "";
        var follow = this;
        $http.get('/Home/CheckFollower?idToFollow=' + profileId + '&followerId=' + currentUserId).
        success(function(data) {
          //check if it is a follower
          if (data) {
            // Not following - Show unfollow
            alert("1111");
            follow.statusMessage = data;
          } else {
            //Following - show Follow
            follow.statusMessage = data;
          }
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
          console.log(data);
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Just curious,  before this solution,  I tried to create a function and use a return.  However,  it kept running the function over and over.   Do you have any idea why it would do that?

Comment: @JeremyLewallen I didn't get you on this point..about what function you are talking about?

Comment: I created a function called checkFollower(). It had the same logic as above, except it used return.   WHen I called the function with angular binding {{ checkFollower() }}     it stayed in an infinite loop.  Just curious if you would know why that would happen